# Save sent mail to user's sent items folder

Tags: java, spring, exchangewebservices

I use the EWS-Java-API.

I have a system where "admin mail" is logged in. Then I have the users with their own mails, sending mails to buyers or something else. Right now when a user send a mail, it's saving the mail in the admins "SENT ITEMS folder", but I want them to get saved in the user's folder.

```
Mailbox mb = new Mailbox();
mb.setAddress(from.trim());
FolderId SentFolderForUser = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, mb);
emailMessage.sendAndSaveCopy(SentFolderForUser);
```

Caused by:

> microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceResponseException: The specified object was not found in the store., The process failed to get the correct properties.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means "admin mail" doesn't have rights to the SentItems folder of the user in mb (you can test this simply by trying to bind to the Folder first)

Folder SendItems = Folder.Bind(service, SentFolderForUser);

You need to give the "admin mail" user access to the Mailbox via Add-Mailboxpermission https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124097(v=exchg.160).aspx .

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah that's fails too. Do you know how i can edit permissions online?

Comment: EDIT: Full Access Permission from Office 365 you need to access the Admin Center at https://portal.office.com  , then go to Exchange Admin Center > Recipients > Mailboxes > Double click on user > Mailbox Delegation and scroll down to the bottom of the page until you see "Full Access" . Click on "+" to add users as full access permitted on this mailbox and that's all you need to do . The permissions may take time to apply so the changes may not be effective immediately .